# Using singleton with shared preferences?

Tags: android, singleton, sharedpreferences

I am using singleton to store global data on my application.
In this part of the data has been downloaded online and other has been already saved in the preferences.

```
 public class MySingleton {
        private static MySingleton mInstance;

        private MySingleton() {

        }

        public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance() {
            if (mInstance == null) {
                mInstance = new MySingleton();
            }
            return mInstance;

        }
    private City city; // I download the city online
    private int userId; // I save the userId in the preferences

    public City getCity(){
    return city;
    }
    public void setCity(City city){
    this.city = city;
    }

    public int getUserId(){
    return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId){
    this.userId = userId;
    }
```

I downloaded the cityObject online in the first activity and then set them on the singleton object;

my problem is when the app was in the background the operating system kill the app and object city then the singleton become null ;

My solution is to save the city object in the preferences, when I downloaded the first activity, and when the city is null i get it from the preferences instead of the internet.

is this wise to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can 'convert' your city object into a JSON and save it as String in your sharedPreferences. When you come back, you can read the JSON string and convert it back to a City object.

You can easily achieve that by using [Gson Library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). See these examples:

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples

Comment: that's a good idea thank you, actually every time the singleton become null, I restart it from the preferences. and then i will use the singleton instead of the preferences , i do that because I think this is faster , is this right ?

Comment: It's good to have a class to 'coordinate' the job of collecting the data from internet and storing it on the preferences..so the 'user' of this class doesn't know about these details. If you want to encapsulate that in this singleton it's fine.